# Improve my Haskell implementation of Filter

Tags: haskell, filter

I have recently been teaching myself Haskell, and one of my exercises was to re-implement the `filter` function. However, of all the exercises I have performed, my answer for this one seems to me the most ugly and long. How could I improve it? Are there any Haskell tricks I don't yet know?

```
myfilter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
myfilter f (x:xs) = if f x
    then x : myfilter f xs
    else myfilter f xs
myfilter _ [] = []
```

Thank You

Comment: I for one don't find it ugly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The simplest way to neaten your implementation is to use [guards](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html#sect4.1).  Instead of `pattern = value`, you can write write `pattern | boolean = value`; this will only match when `boolean` is true.  Thus, we can get

```
filter1 :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter1 p (x:xs) | p x       = x : filter1 p xs
                 | otherwise = filter1 p xs
filter1 _ []                 = []
```

(Note that `otherwise` is just a synonym for `True`.)  Now, we have `filter p xs` in two places, so we can move it out into a `where` clause; these are shared by everything which shares a common pattern, even if it has a different guard:

```
filter2 :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter2 p (x:xs) | p x       = x : xs'
                 | otherwise = xs'
  where xs' = filter2 p xs
filter2 _ []                 = []
```

(This implementation is the one [used by GHCs Prelude](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/src/GHC-List.html#filter).)

Now, neither of these are tail-recursive.  This can be disadvantageous, but it does make the function lazy.  If we want a tail-recursive version, we could write

```
filter3 :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter3 p xs = let filter3' p (x:xs) ys | p x       = next $! x:ys
                                        | otherwise = next $! ys
                     where next = filter3' p xs
                   filter3' _ []     ys             = reverse ys
               in filter3' p xs []
```

Note, however, that this would fail on infinite lists (though all the other implementations will work), thanks to the `reverse`, so we make it strict with `$!`.  (I think I did this right—I could have forced the wrong variable.  I think I got this one right, though.)

Those implementations all look like yours.  There are, of course, others.  One is based on `foldr`:

```
filter4 :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter4 p = let check x | p x       = (x :)
                        | otherwise = id
            in foldr check []
```

We take advantage of point-free style here; since `xs` would be the last argument to both `filter4` and `foldr check []`, we can elide it, and similarly with the last argument of `check`.

You could also take advantage of the list monad:

```
import Control.Monad
filter5 :: MonadPlus m => (a -> Bool) -> m a -> m a
filter5 p xs = do x <- xs
                  guard $ p x
                  return x
```

The list monad represents nondeterminism.  You pick an element `x` from `xs`, make sure that it satisfies `p`, and then return it if it does.  All of these results are then collected together.  But note that this is now more general; this works for any `MonadPlus` (a monad which is also a monoid; that is, which has an associative binary operation `mplus`—`++` for lists—and an identity element `mzero`—`[]` for lists), such as `[]` or `Maybe`.  For instance, `filter5 even $ Just 1 == Nothing`, and `filter5 even $ Just 2 == Just 2`.

We can also adapt the `foldr`-based version to get a different generic type signature:

```
import Control.Monad
import qualified Data.Foldable as F
import qualified Data.Monoid   as M
filter6 :: (F.Foldable f, MonadPlus m, M.Monoid (m a))
        => (a -> Bool) -> f a -> m a
filter6 p = let check x | p x       = return x
                        | otherwise = mzero
            in F.foldMap check
```

The [Data.Foldable module](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Data-Foldable.html) provides the `Foldable` type class, which represents any structure which can be `fold`ed like a list (placing the result in a generic `Monoid` instead.)  Our `filter` requires a `MonadPlus` constraint on the result as well so that we can write `return x`.  The `foldMap` function requires a function which converts everything to elements of a `Monoid`, and then concatenates all of them together.  The mismatch between the `f a` on the left and the `m a` on the right means you could, for instance, `filter6` a `Maybe` and get back a list.

I'm sure that there are (many!) other implementations of `filter`, but these are the 6 that I could think of relatively quickly.  Now, which of these do I actually like best?  It's a tossup between the straightforward `filter2` and the `foldr`-based `filter4`.  And `filter5` is nice for its generic type signature.  (I don't think I've ever needed a type signature like `filter6`'s.)  The fact that `filter2` is used by GHC is a plus, but GHC also uses some funky rewrite rules, so it's not obvious to me that it's superior without those.  Personally, I would *probably* go with `filter4` (or `filter5` if I needed the genericity), but `filter2` is definitely fine.

Comment: The original filter is not tail recursive, but tail corecursive (if I may make up a term).  This is the way list processing functions in Haskell should be, since then they can work lazily and in constant space.  I've found tail recursion to be fairly rare in Haskell, actually.

Comment: luqui: Oh, definitely.  But if you have something that *is* strict, it can be nice to have the tail-recursive version—that's why `foldl'` is nice, but `foldl` is less useful.

Comment: Note that the recursion in `filter1` is mediated by a heap-allocated thunk.  In the first case, `filter1` returns a heap-allocated cons cell, which when forced, will call `filter1`.  So it's an indirect mutual recursion that runs in constant stack space.

Comment: Norman: I think I follow that.  Good call.  I'm not entirely used to reasoning about laziness yet.  (Also, thanks for catching the `filter`/`filter1` mistake.)

Comment: Typo in your first two examples, "f x" should be "p x".

Answer (score 7):

How about a list comprehension?

```
myfilter f xs = [x | x <- xs, f x]
```

Comment: How about `myfilter = filter`?

Answer (score 3):

You could at least DRY it up a bit by pulling out that common `myfilter f xs` code:

```
myfilter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
myfilter f (x:xs) = if f x
    then x : rest
    else rest
        where rest = myfilter f xs
myfilter _ [] = []
```

Answer (score 2):

For comparison, here's Wikipedia's implementation:

```
myfilter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
myfilter _ []                 = []
myfilter f (x:xs) | f x       = x : myfilter f xs
                  | otherwise = myfilter f xs
```

Answer (score 1):

In Haskell, most of the time you can (and should) use [guards](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#guards-guards) instead of if-then-else:

```
myfilter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
myfilter f (x:xs)
   | f x       = x : myfilter f xs
   | otherwise = myfilter f xs
myfilter _ [] = []
```

This ends up being basically the same definition as used [in the standard library](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/src/GHC-List.html#filter).